# encoding issue in python scriaping

Tags: python, web-scraping, character-encoding, python-unicode, unicode-string

```
<div class="features clearfix">
<span> <img src="/App_Theme/css/img/ico_area.png" width="36" height="36" class="imgvertical">
                78,00 a 207,00 m²             
</span>
<span><img src="/App_Theme/css/img/ico_bed.png" class="imgvertical"></i>  

                            Desde&nbsp;
                            2
            </span> 
<span><img src="/App_Theme/css/img/ico_bath.png" width="36" height="36" class="imgvertical">

                    Desde&nbsp;
                    2        
</span> 
<span><img src="/App_Theme/css/img/ico_garaje.png" width="36" class="imgvertical" height="36">  
                Sin especificar  
</span> 
</div>
```

Trying to scrap data inside the above tag, however the output string print only unreadable characters, not the correct data

My code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get('https://www.fincaraiz.com.co/oceana-52/barranquilla/proyecto-nuevo-det-1041165.aspx')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
box_2 = soup.find('div' ,'features clearfix')
box_2_1  = box_2.findAll('span')
box2 = []
for row2 in box_2_1:
    box2.append(row2.text)
print (box2)
```

But it prints output like below

[' \r\n                78,00 a 207,00 m²\r\n                        \r\n            ', '  \r\n                 \r\n                            Desde\xa0\r\n                            2\r\n                    \r\n                            \r\n            ', '\r\n                 \r\n                    Desde\xa0\r\n                    2\r\n\r\n                     \r\n            ', '\r\n                \r\n                Sin especificar\r\n                \r\n            ']

The expected output here is:

78,00 a 207,00 m² 
Desde  2 
Desde  2 
Sin especificar

I've already tried utf-8 encoding along with the code, but it still giving the same output. How could I avoid the unicode errors?

Answer (score 1):

What you are observing is not a unicode problem. The text you extracted does in fact contain newlines (`'\r\n'`) and nonbreaking spaces where the HTML entity `&nbsp;` is converted to `'\xa0'`.

If you need to remove those characters, or perhaps replace them with spaces, you could modify your code like this:

```
for row2 in box_2_1:
    text = row2.text
    text = text.replace('\r\n', ' ')
    text = text.replace('\xa0', ' ')
    box2.append(text)
print(box2)
```

Note that this will still differ from the expected output that you provided above. Your code creates a list in `box2`, so when you print that list you will see square brackets and commas separating the list elements. If you don't want that, you can join the list into a string, with elements separated by spaces, like this:

```
print(' '.join(box2))
```

Comment: In case the inquirer might like an authority: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space.

Comment: I think no one should answer to your questions. You neither make any comment nor mark them as answer. I suppose you don't know how to. Check out this link. Not a single one is answered. https://stackoverflow.com/users/7818121/sudharsonn-s